# Python3 asyncio - running two servers in own thread

Tags: python, python-3.5, python-multithreading, python-asyncio

I have my servers classes inherited from `BaseServer`:

```
class BaseServer(object):

    def __init__(self, host, port):
        self.loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
        asyncio.set_event_loop(self.loop)

        self.instance = asyncio.start_server(self.handle_connection, host = host, port = port)

    async def handle_connection(self, reader: StreamReader, writer: StreamWriter):
        pass

    def start(self):
        # wrapping coroutine into ensure_future to allow it to call from call_soon
        # wrapping into lambda to make it callable
        callback = asyncio.ensure_future(self.instance)
        self.loop.call_soon(lambda: callback)
        self.loop.run_forever()
        self.loop.close()

    def stop(self):
        self.loop.call_soon_threadsafe(self.loop.stop)

    @staticmethod
    def get_instance():
        return BaseServer(None, None)
```

I need two servers running in own thread to processing requests in parallel.
But when I trying to run them as needed, only first server is running. Below how I run them:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
    asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)

    async def run():
        pool = ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=cpu_count())

        await loop.run_in_executor(pool, Server1.get_instance().start)
        await loop.run_in_executor(pool, Server2.get_instance().start)

    loop.run_until_complete(run())
```

1. What am I doing wrong? How to run each server in own thread?
2. When `asyncio.set_event_loop` is calling from `def __init__` I got next error:

> RuntimeError: There is no current event loop in thread 'Thread-1'.

But if I remove `asyncio.set_event_loop` from `def __init__` and move it to `def start` error disappears. Why this happened?

Comment: You don't really get anything by running the servers in different threads. Running several servers in the same loop do not prevent the requests to be processed concurrently.

Comment: @Vincent but running two servers via run_until_complete in the same loop blocks loop for one of servers to process request to another, isn't it ? How to run two servers correctly ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Following up on OP's comment:

> But running two servers via run_until_complete in the same loop blocks loop for one of servers to process request to another, isn't it ? How to run two servers correctly ?

Here is a modified version of the [TCP server example](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/asyncio-stream.html#tcp-echo-server-using-streams) from the asyncio documentation for python 3.5:

```
# Start server 1
coro1 = asyncio.start_server(handle_echo, '127.0.0.1', 8888, loop=loop)
server1 = loop.run_until_complete(coro1)
print('Serving 1 on {}'.format(server1.sockets[0].getsockname()))

# Start server 2
coro2 = asyncio.start_server(handle_echo, '127.0.0.1', 8889, loop=loop)
server2 = loop.run_until_complete(coro2)
print('Serving 2 on {}'.format(server2.sockets[0].getsockname()))

# Serve requests until Ctrl+C is pressed
try:
    loop.run_forever()
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    pass

# Close the servers
server1.close()
loop.run_until_complete(server1.wait_closed())
server2.close()
loop.run_until_complete(server2.wait_closed())

# Close the loop
loop.close()
```

Note that with python 3.7 additions to asyncio, it would look [much nicer](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/asyncio-stream.html#tcp-echo-server-using-streams):

```
async def main():
    server1 = await asyncio.start_server(
        handle_echo, '127.0.0.1', 8888)

    addr1 = server1.sockets[0].getsockname()
    print(f'Serving 1 on {addr1}')

    server2 = await asyncio.start_server(
        handle_echo, '127.0.0.1', 8889)

    addr2 = server2.sockets[0].getsockname()
    print(f'Serving 2 on {addr2}')

    async with server1, server2:
        await asyncio.gather(
            server1.serve_forever(), server2.serve_forever())

asyncio.run(main())
```

Comment: Got it! Thanks a lot

Comment: Nice upgrade to the py3.7 idiom. You might want the last line to be something like `await asyncio.gather(server1.serve_forever(), server2.serve_forever())` for maximum correctness.

Comment: @user4815162342 I was actually wondering about this, why do you think the `gather` approach is more correct?

Comment: `gather` captures the *intention* of waiting until both servers stop serving, whereas `await server1.serve_forever()` makes it look like we're waiting for `server1` and don't care about `server2`. Another option is to use `asyncio.wait` with `FIRST_COMPLETED` and cancel the other one, but that's too much typing. In practice there is very little difference along those, since neither server is expected to stop serving in isolation.

Comment: Can this be done also with the web app? (aiohttp.web) instead of a simple tcp server? I cannot figure out the snipplet so it works with gather.